# Implementing the Repository Pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns, entity-framework

I'm new to this pattern and I see arguments online about different implementations. I have the following code and it seems fine to me, **but I'm wondering if having to pass the DBContext into the constructor would cause any issues down the line?** I'm using this with EntityFramework (RECORD_TYPE is a table brought in from EF).

I'm a little newer to unit testing as well, so I'm thinking I would have to make a mock context in my unit tests that basically return a list of RECORD_TYPE objects that I create in the mock DBContext I make.

**Am I missing any ideas with this?**

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    IQueryable<T> All { get; }
    T Find(int id);
    void Save();
}

public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private DbContext context;

    public Repository(DbContext c)
    {
        context = c;
    }

    public IQueryable<T> All { get { return context.Set<T>(); } }

    public T Find(int id)
    {
        return context.Set<T>().Find(id);
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}

public class RecordTypeRepository : Repository<RECORD_TYPE>
{
    public RecordTypeRepository(DbContext context)
        : base(context)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: you might want to read this: http://www.wekeroad.com/2014/03/04/repositories-and-unitofwork-are-not-a-good-idea/

Comment: @Zdeslav this is exactly the reason I made this post. When you search this online you get a million different ways and views on it. It's enough to drive a person insane. However, the reason I was looking into it was because of doing unit tests. I don't want to hit my database (and everything I do uses a database) because I don't want to have my database be in the right state (it's a pain). So I want an easy way to mock the db context so I can manually fill it with data to use for testing. This then opens up a big wormhole in all the possibilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion using the repository pattern is absolutely fine, for a number of reasons, not limited to:

1. It enables unit testing
2. Allows you to change EF for a another DB technology

The detail that you have to be careful of using the base class is that you make sure that you declare properties/variables via the interface and not via the base class. So consider this:

**Good**

```
public class Test{
    private IRepository<MyClass> _repo;
}
```

**Bad**

```
public class Test{
    private BaseRepository<MyClass> _repo;
}
```

---

With the actual code, I would suggest a number of changes:

1. The interface should have full CRUD operations
2. Try and use the same name for fetching a record (Consider `Get()` and `Get(id)` vs `All()` and `Get(1)`. It makes it more natural to consumers)
3. The class `Repository` should be marked as abstract to stop you using it directly
4. The class `Repository` should probably be named `EFBaseRepository`

Typically, when I implement the pattern I create the interface followed by a class called `BaseRepository` that implements all the methods. The methods no nothing more than throw a `NotSupportedException`/`NotImplementedException`. This is because I might only want consumers to have read/update but not create. It does depend on the context of the application.